# NetSuite pulling account numbers assoicated with records

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to recreate a program in NetSuite, I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT TL.TRANSACTION_ID,
       T.TRANDATE,
       T.TRANSACTION_TYPE,
       TL.AMOUNT,
       TL.ACCOUNT_ID,
       ET.NAME,
       TO_CHAR(T.TRANDATE - TO_DATE('" & FStartDate & "')),
       T.CLOSED,
       T.STATUS
  FROM TRANSACTION_LINES AS TL
  JOIN TRANSACTIONS AS T
    ON (T.TRANSACTION_ID = TL.TRANSACTION_ID)
  LEFT JOIN ENTITY AS ET
    ON (T.TRANSACTION_ID = TL.TRANSACTION_ID AND ET.ENTITY_ID = T.ENTITY_ID)
 WHERE TL.TRANSACTION_ID IN
       (SELECT TL.TRANSACTION_ID
          FROM TRANSACTION_LINES AS TL
         WHERE TL.ACCOUNT_ID = '135')
   AND T.TRANSACTION_TYPE != 'Paycheck'
   AND TL.ACCOUNT_ID != '135'
   AND T.TRANDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & FStartDate & "', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND
       TO_DATE('" & FEndDate & "', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 ORDER BY ET.NAME
```

So what its doing is grabbing all records from account 135, that are not a paycheck, and removing the results where the account is == '135'.

Through SQL with each transaction its pulling, its pulling more then 1 record.  For example, if it pulls a journal the credit may be associated with account 135, but the debit is associated with account 112.

So the SQL is pulling the credit from account 135, and the debit from 112.  Then removing the credit from 135 and your left with is the debit from 112.  Is it possible to do this within netsuite?

Comment: Is debit/credit indicated by the "TRANSACTION_TYPE" field?

Comment: the "TRANSACTION_TYPE" is pulling the type payment, check, deposit, etc.  Its not necessarily pulling debits and credits because not all records will have a debit and a credit. Its pulling all records associated with the internal ID of a record for journals its pulling the debit and the credit, for transfers its pulling a record for the "from account" and the "to account".  and then which ever record is actually '135' is being dropped.

Comment: It may help if you give a few rows of example source data and your expected output. It's too hard to tell without knowing what the data looks like. Or at least some example rows of output you're getting, with an indication of how you want it to be changed. You can probably use aggregate functions to net things out as needed.

Comment: I think I may have solved it.  I first I did a search and put all the internal id's in an array and did a second search for internal id's using the saved array.  But netsuite went down so i'll try again later.